# Restoring a cPanel/WHM backup

Tags: backup, restore, cpanel, whm

I have a cPanel/WHM backup that I would like to restore on a new system. What I have is the entire backup directory, not compressed. Do I have to compress it into a single file, and move it to the /home directory before I can restore it, or is there a way to do it using the non-compressed directory?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore uncompress backup using restore option available in WHM. You will need single tar.gz file to restore full cPanel account automatically. You should generate tar.gz file for your full cPanel backup and then you can move it to /home to restore it from WHM.